# Why removed apps use mobile data?

Tags: mobile-data

Android 10

When open mobile data usage ,write that removed apps use data.
Why removed  apps use my mobile data,how stops this and how properly delete them forever?
Why they use data if they are uninstalled?

[image]

Comment: That is a monthly total. Did you uninstall those apps a month ago?

Comment: this site dont has purpose if it closed question before someone answer..I find here answer:https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/45vf2v/help_removed_apps_and_users_using_up_2gigs_of_my/   .....now you can delete my question